# spark streaming task always in running status

Tags: task, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming job problem, one task of the job always in a running status and the other tasks are all completed. I found some exception occur in non-stoped task. 
Why an exception occur in the task causes a job does not stop in a "running" status.
Did someone met and solved this problem? Please Help! Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/000wA.png)

Comment: It depends on your application. If you, or the framework you use don't throw this exception, the job will not fail.

Comment: Could you please post your code as well as the error message?

Comment: @bupt_ljy I think you are right , I check my code and throw the exception. I'm looking forward to find the result. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis I think  bupt_ljy  gave me the right answer